# Visual Studio Mac M1: Create android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

i am trying to create an android emulator for my project, however I cannot start the emulator from visual studio, only from android studio.

I find the created emulator in my list of emulators in both IDEs but only on android studio does it start.

This screenshot is from VS 2019:

[image]

You can see that the top emulator play button (created from android studio mac) is blank.

I then created my own emulatores using arm64.v8a architecture, and they both start but both stay blank.

I also noticed that in VS i can only give these emulators android 7.1 max all though i have never SDKs installed but only in 7.1 SDK manager states that there is arm64 included.

How can I start my emulator on M1 Mac from VS 2019 MAC?

Thank you!

Comment: Are all software you use installed as arm64 version (VisualStudio, AndroidStudio, AndroidSDK/emulator)?

Comment: Yes. I ended up using the preview 3 emulator that was discontinued because of the non working native support. this emulator however works and is even faster than the ios one,..

Answer (score 0):

Allthough this states no longer needed, it IS still totally needed.

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview

This will make all your problems dissappear in a heart beats. Supports XAML hot reload and is faster, even than iPhone simulators. Isnt that crazy